# List of possible combinations of elements within a list of list

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have a list that contains 2 list:

```
[['JA@lazo.es', 'HI@lazo.es'], ['PO@jordi.es', 'GA@jordi.es'], '100', '1']
```

How I can combine all the possible combinations between the elements of the first list (position 0) and the second list (position 1) individually and at the same time create a new list with the elements that are not in those two positions of the original list.

So the result would be like:

```
[ 
['HI@lazo.es','PO@jordi.es','100', '1'], 
['HI@lazo.es','GA@jordi.es','100', '1'], 
['JA@lazo.es','PO@jordi.es','100', '1'],
['JA@lazo.es', 'GA@jordi.es','100', '1'] 
]
```

I can assume that the lists within the list will always be at position 0 and 1 but there could be multiple elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but here is a simple way:

1. Create an array for storing all the results, and iterate the first array

```py
all_arrays = []
for a in items[0]:
```

2. Iterate the second array

```py
    for b in items[1]:
```

3. Create a new array consisting of `a`, `b`, and the rest of your items; and append this array to the output

```py
        new_array = [a, b] + items[2:]
        all_arrays.append(new_array)
```

For more reading on generating combinations of lists, I'd suggest checking out the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) module

Comment: There is a small mistake in this line:

**new_array = [a, b] + items[3:]**

You have to change items[3:] to **items[2:]**

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I'll update the answer with that fix